# Proving Inner Product Space Induced Norm Property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Given an inner product space $(H, \langle .,.\rangle)$ and a vector $x \in H$, prove that $$\lVert x \rVert = \sup_{\lVert y \rVert = 1} | \langle x,y \rangle|.$$

My attempt:

Begin with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq \lVert x \rVert \ \lVert y \rVert$$ Take $\lVert y \rVert = 1$, then $$ \lVert x \rVert \geq |\langle x,y \rangle |$$ Now this last part is where I struggle. I don't see how taking the supremum of the RHS guarantees equality seeing as the supremum is a least upper bound and thus does not have to be attained for any $y \in H$. In my mind taking the max of the RHS instead would be more natural. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$ there is nothing to prove. For $x \ne 0$ take $y = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ which is possible, that proves that equality is attainable. Indeed,
$$
\left|\left\langle x,  \frac{x}{\|x\|} \right\rangle\right| = \frac{1}{\|x\|}|\langle x,  x \rangle| = \frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|} = \|x\|
$$
Of course you still have $\|y\|  = 1$.